# My ListView is overlapping on my edittext

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-edittext

Why is that my listview is overlapping on my edittext box I think the problem is my XML coding 
by the way I am using frameLayout I want my listView to be underneath my edittext how can I do it?

Here is my XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Search Bus Station..."
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:background="@drawable/textinputborder"
            android:ems="10"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:textSize="18sp" >

        </EditText>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#111"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" >
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Since you are using a relative layout you can use Below to your listview and say below your edittext

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"` to your `ListView` so that your `ListView` is always gonna be below your `EditText`.

Alternatively, you can add `android:layout_marginTop="10dp"` to your `ListView` and set the margin value as per your needs(not recommended though).

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Search Bus Station..."
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:background="@drawable/textinputborder"
            android:ems="10"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:textSize="18sp" >

    </EditText>

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#111"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" >
    </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use  **android:layout_below** in your listview for reference to create layout see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html).

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Search Bus Station..."
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:background="@drawable/textinputborder"
        android:ems="10"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:textSize="18sp" >

    </EditText>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#111"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" >
    </ListView>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/textinputborder"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Search Bus Station..."
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:textSize="18sp" >
    </EditText>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#111"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_below` attribute

Add  `android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"` to your Listview , below is your updated UI

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/textinputborder"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Search Bus Station..."
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:textSize="18sp" >
    </EditText>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides using `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"` try to set the `android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"` in your `ListView` So your `ListView` will be always below to your `EditText`.